# How to assign "bigger than but smaller than" using Comparison Operators in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, variables, if-statement

I want to do something like this:

```
if (a < 10) {
    println("yes")
} else if (10 < a < 20) {
    println("no")
}
```

apparently I can't do (X < variable < Y)

Sorry if I didn't redacted this so well, hope you get my issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can't. Not Swift related; I wouldn't know any language where you could check for a range like that. I know languages where that code is accepted and gives very unexpected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First condition a > 10. Second condition a < 20. So you just need to use the "&&" operator that means "and" so it needs to satisfy both conditions.

```
let a = 15

if a < 10 {
    println("yes")
} else if a > 10 && a < 20 {
    println("no")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Leonardo Savio Dabus' answer, you can also use `contain()`:

```
let a = 15
if contains(10...20, a) {
    println("no")
}
```

Just something else you can use. In my opinion it looks a tiny bit better.